# What's wrong with the matrix?

Tags: c, matrix

What's wrong with this code?
My task is: Create a square matrix of integers with a size of 9x9. Fill the matrix with random numbers. Display the main and side diagonal symmetrically with respect to the vertical axis. The example of expected result is here: [matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icbsR.jpg)

```
Matrix :

20      20      76      65      93      76      16      2       85

6       87      78      43      48      81      71      90      38

10      12      35      77      48      88      24      53      7 

12      66      51      35      74      7       30      22      49

58      14      71      46      68      68      10      81      51

98      16      74      47      64      25      17      30      37

2       44      44      74      34      54      86      73      28

85      4       57      75      18      28      51      76      2 

35      17      53      76      15      91      83      85      72

The main and side diagonal:

85      20      76      65      93      76      16      2       20

6       90      78      43      48      81      71      87      38

10      12      24      77      48      88      35      53      7 

12      66      51      7       74      35      30      22      49

58      14      71      46      68      68      10      81      51

98      16      74      25      64      47      17      30      37

2       44      86      74      34      54      44      73      28

85      76      57      75      18      29      51      4       2 

72      17      53      76      15      91      83      85      35
```

But in fact the program prints only the main matrix with random numbers and after that stops.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 9;
    int matrix[a][a];
    int temp;
    int i, j, n;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    printf("Matrix : \n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < a; ++j) {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    printf("The main and side diagonal:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
        temp = matrix[i][i];
        matrix[i][i] = matrix[i][(a - 1) - i];
        matrix[i][(a - 1) - i] = temp;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < a; ++j) {
            printf("Result:", matrix[i][j]);
            printf("\n\n\n");
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the expected and the actual result of the code?

Comment: Please **edit  your question** and include what it is that leads you to believe there's a problem. Error messages, wrong output, hordes of screaming aliens descending from the sky when you run your code, other?

Comment: The image should be embedded as 'code' in the question.  It's just a dump of two 9x9 matrices with heading lines.  It looks as if the lines are double spaced (one line of numbers, one line blank).  I've no idea what a 'main and side diagonal matrix' is — and Google isn't telling me in words of three syllables or fewer either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning where you are not supposed to. (in middle of the calculation). You should return after you end up working on the for loops.

```
for (i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < a; ++j) {
            printf("Result:", matrix[i][j]); <--- Not printing element
            printf("\n\n\n");
            system("pause");
            return 0; <-----
        }
    }
```

It should be

```
for (i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < a; ++j) {
            printf("Result: %d ", matrix[i][j]); <----You forgot the
                                                //format specifier
            printf("\n\n\n");
            system("pause");

        }
    }
  return 0;<-----
```

Readability is hampered when the indentation is like this. You implemented wrong logic out of it.

---

- OP asks that it stops after printing "Result" that is because you forgot to put the format specifier in the code. That's why none of the element is printed.

---

Op wants to print the *main and side diagonal symmetrically with respect to the vertical axis*.

Now this is everything to with the print part.

Now we have to find a way that will let us distinguish which one is diagonal element and which one is not.

Suprisingly the answer should be known to someone who is writing the previous swapping logic. (Though it is not clear why OP swapped it).

Now all element `matrix[p][q]` will be from either diagonal if `p=q` or `p+q=a-1`. (Note that `matrix` is a square matrix).

---

But OP meant to print the matrix

---

```
for (i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
        if( i == 0) printf("The main and side diagonal : \n");
        for (j = 0; j < a; ++j) {
            printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
          }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did it, but the problem still persists... Can't understand where's the problem.

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин.: What is the problem? You wanted to generate random matrix and print it?

Comment: I want to print random matrix and side (secondary) matrix diagonal symmetrically with respect to the vertical axis. But the program prints random matrix and strings "The main and side diagonal:" and "Result:" and after that stops.

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин.: So you want to print the diagonal like this `a[0][0] a[0][2] a[1][1] a[1][1] a[0][2] a[2][2]`???

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин.: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[What do I do when someone answers my
question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин.: Check my answer

Comment: Added the example of expected result to the description. So in fact I've got only the first matrix.

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин.: Hope it helps now. I have edited. Your swap logic is right. But you were not printing the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use functions.  You print the matrix twice; you should have a function to print the matrix which you call twice.

With such a function, you'd not make the mistakes in the tail end of your code.  For example, you could use this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static void print_matrix(const char *tag, int size, int matrix[size][size])
{
    printf("%s (%dx%d):\n\n", tag, size, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        const char *pad = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        {
            printf("%s%-2d", pad, matrix[i][j]);
            pad = "      ";
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned seed = time(0);
    int a = 9;
    int matrix[a][a];

    if (argc == 2)
        seed = atoi(argv[1]);
    srand(seed);
    printf("Seed: %u\n", seed);

    for (int i = 0; i < a; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a; ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 100;
    }

    print_matrix("Matrix", a, matrix);

    for (int i = 0, j = a - 1; i < a; ++i, --j)
    {
        int temp = matrix[i][i];
        matrix[i][i] = matrix[i][j];
        matrix[i][j] = temp;
    }

    print_matrix("The main and side diagonal", a, matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

The code reports the seed it uses; that allows you to reproduce any run by specifying the seed to use as a command line argument.

Example output:

```
Seed: 1511470282
Matrix (9x9):

11      39      3       88      98      63      75      81      76

93      9       60      22      45      50      46      58      65

13      99      25      43      14      57      44      70      65

30      57      55      0       37      84      47      49      40

60      28      46      1       96      78      33      20      9 

93      61      11      38      84      16      91      26      15

43      85      66      72      85      39      96      45      45

45      25      33      3       78      90      61      65      62

88      84      56      34      74      8       78      57      74

The main and side diagonal (9x9):

76      39      3       88      98      63      75      81      11

93      58      60      22      45      50      46      9       65

13      99      44      43      14      57      25      70      65

30      57      55      84      37      0       47      49      40

60      28      46      1       96      78      33      20      9 

93      61      11      16      84      38      91      26      15

43      85      96      72      85      39      66      45      45

45      65      33      3       78      90      61      25      62

74      84      56      34      74      8       78      57      88
```

The swapping process, in case it isn't obvious, swaps the first and last elements of the first row, the second and last but one element in the second row, and so on, forming an X of swapped elements.